# FireMonkey Drag & Drop Issue

Tags: drag-and-drop, firemonkey

I'm coding a manual drag, which, by instance, drags a `tRectangle` inside a `tPanel` (the parent), but could be any object inside other object (the parent).

I'm handling the `OnMouseDown` rectangle's event and the `OnMouseMove` parent's event. At the `OnMouseDown` event, I set the parent to capture the mouse events, and at the `OnMouseMove` event, I set the new rectangle's position, accordingly to a fixed displacement value. The rectangle is properly dragged, but the mouse cursor ends outside the rectangle when it is dropped. I tried to set the `X` coordinate inside the rectangle, but no matter the value I set to `X`, it always increases or decreases by one pixel. I appreciate any help for solving this issue. Follows an image showing the start and end position of the rectangle and the mouse cursor.

[image]

Comment: "always increases or decreases by one pixel". That picture looks like the cursor is off by more than one pixel. Why is that?

Comment: Yes. In fact, the actual mouse displaycement is more than one pixel, and the rectangle moves accordingly. The issue is that the mouse cursor is moving one pixel at a time, no matter how the mouse device is moving, hence, the **_mouse cursor_** at start dragging is at the center of the rectangle and at stop dragging ends at the right of the rectangle. My goal is to make the mouse cursor stay at the same X, Y coordinates inside the rectangle, as they where at start dragging.